# Laravel hasMany. Сортировка полей через связи

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет.
У меня есть таблицы eds, tk, tk_status. У eds связь к tk hasMany, у tk связь к tk_status hasMany. Со фронта мне приходит статус (например, доставлен), по которому мы должны фильтровать результат. Сделал сортировку следующим образом:

```
return $query->when($request->query('tk_status'), function (Builder $query, $tk_status) {
            $query->join('tk', 'tk.ed_id', '=', 'eds.id')
                ->join('tk_status', 'tk_status.id', '=', 'tk.tk_status_id')
                ->whereRaw('LOWER(tk_status.name) LIKE \''.mb_strtolower($tk_status).'\'')
                ->select('eds.*');
        });
```

Но получаю не только tk со статусом добавлен, но и с другим статусом.

```
{
        "id": 430,
        "name": "ed2",
        "num": "123",
        "reg_date": "2020-12-12",
        "source_ed_id": "123",
        "save_period": 1,
        "source": {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "Департамент кадрового делопроизводства Министерства цифрового развития"
        },
        "dossier": null,
        "attr_values": [],
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 428,
                "file_role": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": "Приложение"
                },
                "uri": "media/ead/430/1.txt",
                "size": 0,
                "name": "1.txt",
                "file_ext": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "value": "txt"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 429,
                "file_role": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "value": "Спецификация документа"
                },
                "uri": "media/ead/430/2.txt",
                "size": 0,
                "name": "2.txt",
                "file_ext": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "value": "txt"
                },
                "parent_file": [
                    {
                        "id": 428,
                        "name": "1.txt",
                        "file_ext": {
                            "id": 7,
                            "value": "txt"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "tk": [
            {
                "id": 235,
                "form_date": "2021-06-02 12:08:22",
                "status": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "value": "доставлен"
                    }
                ],
                "archive": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": "Российский государственный архив экономики"
                    }
                ],
                "fund": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "archive_id": 1,
                        "value": "Фонды учреждений"
                    }
                ],
                "send_date": "2021-06-02 12:08:22",
                "sign_end_date": null,
                "tk_path": "",
                "ep_path": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 233,
                "form_date": "2021-06-02 11:56:39",
                "status": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": "отправлен"
                    }
                ],
                "archive": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": "Российский государственный архив экономики"
                    }
                ],
                "fund": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "archive_id": 2,
                        "value": "Маркс (Marx) Карл (1818–1883), Энгельс (Engels) Фридрих (1820–1895)"
                    }
                ],
                "send_date": "2021-06-02 11:56:39",
                "sign_end_date": null,
                "tk_path": "media/tk/233/b4b48d40-c39b-11eb-a369-7345543b5988.edc/233.zip",
                "ep_path": ""
            }
        ]
    }
```

С помощью $query->toSql посмотреть запрос, выполнил его в бд, он верный.

```
select "eds".* from "eds" left join "tk" on "tk"."ed_id" = "eds"."id" left join "tk_status" on "tk_status"."id" = "tk"."tk_status_id" where LOWER(tk_status.name) LIKE 'доставлен'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->leftJoin('tk', 'tk.ed_id', '=', 'eds.id')
                ->where('tk.tk_status_id', $tk_status)
                ->whereIn('tk.form_date', function ($query) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(tk.form_date)'))
                        ->from('tk')
                        ->groupBy('tk.ed_id');
                })
                ->select('eds.*');
```

Решил таким вызовом, может быть, кому-то пригодится